# Is it possible to pass the install directory from one installer to another one within a Wix Bundle?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, burn

I have a WiX Bundle for two installers. The second installer must know the installation directory of the first installer. The directory shall be chosen via the first installer's UI. Is there a way to pass the installation directory from the first to the second installer?

What I managed until now (which would also be a fallback option) is to set the install path from the bundle via the "Options" menu and then to read it inside the two installers. However I would prefer to set the install path in the first installer, not in the bundle. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first installer could record it somewhere ( registry ) and the second installer could read that and use it.

Or

Run both installers silently, handle the UI in your bootstrapper application and have it pass to both installers what installation location to use.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your answer. I will try the registry but I fear it will be a bit of a Jacky solution (e.g. I would need to erase the registry entry if the installation is canceled). Handling the UI in the bootstrapper is a possibility but it would mean porting the installer UI to the bootstrapper which is a bigger hassle.

Comment: If the install is cancelled, it should rollback removing the registry entry.